# How to properly make models dynamic for django_tables2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views, django-tables2

Although very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836417/request-object-passed-to-django-tables2-tables-class) mine is different since I am using class based views (instead of function based views).

I'm trying to make the model in my table class dynamic (using django_tables2).

```
class DynamicTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = dynamic_model_here
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html'
```

I am using the SingleTableView (which is pretty much SingleTableMixin) and have not found a good way to pass information (the model) from my view to the 'Meta' section of the Table class. **How can I do this?** <--this is the main question. Below is my current attempt which seems a bit hacky.

I can successfully, dynamically import the model in the before_render() function (thanks to having access to the request) but I can not expose it to Meta [since before_render does not return anything](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/django_tables2/tables.html?highlight=tables.Table).

```
class DynamicTable(tables.Table):

    def before_render(self, request):
        path_info = request.path_info
        current_model_name = path_info.replace('/','')
        current_model_import = __import__(module_path, fromlist = current_model_name)
        current_model = getattr(current_model_import, current_model_name)   
        model = current_model
        return #The source code shows that before_render just returns nothing

    class Meta:
        model = dynamic_model_here
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html'
```

What this shows me is that if I could some how handle the request within the same object as Metal.model I would be good-to-go.

So my current route is to try to access request which is a django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest from the view in the same object as Meta. How could I do that? And if anyone can recommend a better or built-in way to pass parameters to the Meta class of the table class - that would be ideal.

Comment: Please reopen; I would just like to put the answer for anyone who is using CBV. I think I figured it out: I just put it in the context in the get_context_data function.